# Drag and drop from C# to Outlook

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, outlook

I have a document control system that is written in C#. Drag and drop ***from Outlook to C# has been done for some time***. Now that many of the files are in the C# application, the users naturally want to be able to drag and drop ***in the other direction*** *from* my document control system *to* Outlook.

Since the files are stored in a file system (and not as blobs in the SQL database) I have had them open the folder view and drag and drop from there. However, this allows for the bypassing of the document management system's version control.

***Is there a drag and drop message I can construct that will notify Outlook of the filename and path I'm dropping?*** I suspect this has been done, but my searches are being overwhelmed by the number of responses going the other direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/f57ffd5d-0fe3-4f64-bfd6-428f58998603/

```
//put the file path is a string array
string[] files = new String[1];
files[0] = @"C:\out.txt";

//create a dataobject holding this array as a filedrop
DataObject data = new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, files);

//also add the selection as textdata
data.SetData(DataFormats.StringFormat, files[0]);

//do the dragdrop
DoDragDrop(data, DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

Comment: Well heck, that looks way too easy. Document and Google search failure on my part... testing now.

Comment: For some reason, whilst this works to drag and drop to the desktop in both VS debug and as an exe, it will only work to Outlook as an exe.  (Win 8.1, VS2013, Outlook 2013)

Answer (score 0):

There is a sequence of steps you have to follow

1. Choose the `Allow Drop` property to be `true`
2. Add event listeners (`DragEnter` & `DragDrop`)
3. Add this code to your cs file

   ```
   private void splitContainer1_Panel2_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("FileDrop", false))
           e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
       else
           e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
   }

   private void splitContainer1_Panel2_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
   {
       string[] files = new String[1];
       files[0] = @"C:\out.txt";
       //create a dataobject holding this array as a filedrop
       DataObject data = new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, files);
       //also add the selection as textdata
       data.SetData(DataFormats.StringFormat, files[0]);
       //do the dragdrop
       DoDragDrop(data, DragDropEffects.Copy);
       if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("FileDrop", false))
       {
           string[] paths = (string[])(e.Data.GetData("FileDrop", false));
           foreach (string path in paths)
           {
                // in this line you can have the paths to add attachements to the email
               Console.WriteLine(path);
           }
       }
   }
   ```